# command for joining a series of files together

Tags: command-line

I have...

> me@computer:~/gutenberg/euclid$ ls
>
> book01.html  book04.html  book07.html
> book10.html  book13.html book02.html
> book05.html  book08.html  book11.html
> book03.html  book06.html  book09.html
> book12.html

and I want to join all these .html files into the same big file, in order. What command or command sequence can I use?

Comment: Are each on of these files, valid html files with a <head> and <body> section?

Comment: @freethinker yes, but it's not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case `cat book??.html > book.html` will work fine, if you don't care about proper HTML format.

For a more general case, say you had "book1.html" instead of "book01.html", "book2.html" instead of "book02.html" and so forth.  The file names don't sort lexically the same as logically. You can do something like this:

```
(echo book?.html | sort; echo book??.html | sort) | xargs cat > book.html
```

So in general: `script_generating_file_names_in_order | xargs cat > all_one_file`

That idiom can go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

I buy the remarks about head/tail, and have a solution, sorted by number without that xargs/sort/echo stuff.

```
cat book{01..12}.html book-all.html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU sort you can use `sort -V` to sort the names in the correct order:

```
$ echo -e "book4\nbook2\nbook17\nbook12" | sort -V
book2
book4
book12
book17
```

This works for any number of files:

```
ls book*.html | sort -V | xargs cat > allbooks.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution will probably work, if your browser is permissiv.

```
cat book[0-9]*.html > book.html
```

Sure you could go around stripping stuff to be probably slightly more legal:

```
perl -e 'undef($/); for($x=0;$x<=$#ARGV;$x++) { open(X,"<",$ARGV[$x]); $_ = <X>; close(X); s/.*<body[^>]*>//s unless ($x == 0);  s|</body>|| unless ($x == $#ARGV); print;' book[0-9]*.html > book.html
```

But that is no guarantee that you will really have everything you need either, if the chapters have different styles or javascript or whatever.